# Regex that accepts: letters, numbers, and some secondary characters with a range of lengths

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my regex test function:

```
function RegexText(val) { 
    var MyRegex = /^([a-z0-9 _àèìòù-]+)$/i;
    var result = MyRegex.exec(val);
    return result !== null && result[0] === val;
}
```

This regex accepts:

- letters (`AbcABC` thanks to the `/i`)
- numbers
- some secondary characters: `à`, `è`, `ì`, `ò`, `ù`, `-`, `_`, and `space`

I also want to insert a range length (min 1 char and max 20 char). I tried to insert `{1,20}`, but without success.

Comment: put the {} after the character class

Comment: Just use the textbox's maxlength attribute.  That way they cannot possibly type in more than 20 characters.

Comment: What string are you testing this on? you have the `^` and `$` anchors which will only allow a match if it is at the start and end of the string being searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the repetition quantifier `{}` next to the character class.

```
var MyRegex = /^[a-z0-9 _àèìòù-]{1,20}$/i;
```

**OR**

Use a lookahead at the start.

```
var MyRegex = /^(?=.{1,20}$)[a-z0-9 _àèìòù-]+$/i;
```

`^(?=.{1,20}$)` only the strings which has the character length ranges from 1 to 20 is allowed.